# Getting error in Progress Dialog in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a MainActivity which adds fragment "A",In fragment"A" I am sending some server request using volley.I had made a class known as DialogUtil which contain progress Dialog implementation.Problem is that when I launch app it shows error in Progress dialog implementation in Fragment "A".That is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42759d68
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager and
>   becomes force close.

DialogUtil class code:-

```
   public class DialogUtils {

    public static ProgressDialog showProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
        ProgressDialog m_Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        m_Dialog.setMessage(message);
        m_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        m_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        m_Dialog.show();
        return m_Dialog;
    }
}
```

Progress dialog implementation in Fragment "A"

```
m_Dialog = DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getContext(), "Loading...");

        final String m_DealListingURL = "http://202.131.1.132:8080/ireward/rest/json/metallica/getDealListInJSON";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                if (m_Dialog != null && m_Dialog.isShowing()) {
                    m_Dialog.dismiss();
                }
```

Comment: Instead of getContext() pass getActivity()

Comment: +1. Same Problem. I also have Daily 5 to 10 crash mails of users for this error. I use getActivity() but no success.

Comment: Hi.

Inside a fragment, you should use getActivity() as mentioned above.

In my DialogUtils methods, my first line is always 

if(activity == null || activity.isFinishing())  return;

Dialogs can throw NPE when used inside fragments if they are being called asynchronously.

Comment: Then where we have to use

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DialogUtils.showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Loading...");
```

Use getActivity() instead of getContext()

Answer (score 1):

you should use getActivity() instead of getContext().

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the method asynchronously?

If you are, the chances are, user has exited the context(fragment, activity or application) by the time the code runs that is creating the dialog, which is bad in multiple ways.

You can solve this problem, if you're running a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for example, by calling in `onDestroy` the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)s [cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) method, but the specific usecase doesn't come clear from the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in calling code in fragment life cycle. Please make sure you are calling dialog after onActivityCreated.